# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Bioinformatics's [second moderator election](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves as pro-tem mods, so the team would have a total of 3 moderators (more on mods stepping down below):

[image: terdon] [image: M__]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please also join me in thanking the following two users, who'll be stepping down from their positions as moderators:

[image: Kamil S Jaron]  [image: Devon Ryan]

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @terdon and @M__ for stepping up!

Comment: Thank _you_ for stepping up first!